# Wort für "kleines Problem"

Tags: single-word-request, vocabulary

Ich bin auf der Suche nach einem Wort (Adjektiv/Subjektiv), welches dem Wort *Problem* die Problemhaftigkeit nimmt.
Denn es ist ja so, dass mit dem Wort *Problem* eine negative Ansicht einhergeht, was ja auch nicht sinnlos ist.
Aber wenn man eben nicht sagen möchte "Ich habe kleine Probleme". Sondern eben ich habe "Problemchen". Dann - hoffe ich - gibt es vielleicht auch eine Variante, die nicht nur die verniedlichte Version des Wortes darstellt.

Comment: Es gibt keine Probleme, nur Herausforderungen ;)

Comment: Ich finde den Kontext nicht ganz unerheblich. Zum Beispiel würde keines der Wörter von @bummi 's Antwort passen, wenn man von "Getriebe-Probleme" redet. Redest du von Problemen mit deinem neuen Chef, wäre eine Umschreibung mit eines der vorgeschlagenen Wörtern möglich, ist aber auch nicht das Wahre. Daher Kontext :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Die Formulierungen

> ```
> Herausforderung
> Anforderung
> Aufgabe
> Challenge
> ```

dürften den negativen Beigeschmack nehmen.

> ```
> Hindernis
> Knackpunkt
> Tücke
> Erschwernis
> ```

Das Problem einfach nur "verkleinern"

Comment: Für mich persönlich ist Erschwernis der Favorit. Denn all zu negativ ist das nicht. Damit wurde meine Frage gelöst. Danke

Comment: Ich würde Anglizismen with `Challenge` nicht empfehlen.

Comment: "Die Formulierungen (...) dürften den negativen Beigeschmack nehmen." - das wage ich zu bezweifeln, gerade, weil Begriffe wie "Herausforderung" so weitverbreitete Euphemismen für "Problem" sind. Und wenn ich sage "Korrekte Rechtschreibung stellt für ihn eine Herausforderung dar.", dann klingt das mE absolut nicht positiver, als wenn ich direkt das Wort "Problem" benutze.

Answer (score 6):

Wenn die Probleme noch erledigt werden können, wird das mit `Offene Punkte` recht wertfrei beschrieben.

Answer (score 0):

Ein `Umstand` nimmt dem Problem auch einen Teil seiner Negativität.